# Cannot read property 'radCCType' of undefined when creating if statements with radio buttons javascript

Tags: javascript, html

keep getting an error when I run my program Cannot read property 'radCCType' of undefined. Im trying to allow the used to select the option with radio buttons then use an else if to find out which one the clicked in javascript.

Heres the code:

```
if (document.frmInput.radCCType[0].checked == true) {
    cardType = "Freshman";
}
else if (document.frmInput.radCCType[1].checked == true) {
    cardType = "Sophomore";
}
else if (document.frmInput.radCCType[2].checked == true) {
    cardType = "Junior";
}
    else if (document.frmInput.radCCType[3].checked == true) {
    cardType = "Senior";
}
```

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="radCCType" value="F" />Freshman <br />
    <input type="radio" name="radCCType" value="S" />Sophomore <br />
    <input type="radio" name="radCCType" value="J" />Junior <br />
    <input type="radio" name="radCCType" value="Sr" />Senior
</form>
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says: there is no such thing as `document.frmInput`, so it doesn't have any properties. You need to either a) get the form element by id (`document.getElementById('myFormId');`) and THEN grab the inputs, or assign a class to the inputs and query against that, or give the form a name and use `document.forms.myFormName.elements`

Comment: Thanks man! I just went and gave the form the name frmInput and it ran the first time! Thanks so much! If you put this as an answer ill vote and set it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you are trying to access properties on a non-object, specifically, `document.frmInput`. This doesn't exist -- there is no "document.frmInput", so when you try and access a property of that, `document.frmInput.radCCType`, you get an error.

You can use a couple of approaches, `document.querySelector` is probably the easiest, and is available in [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) (importantly, IE 8+). Watch out for mobile -- if you need to support mobile, you are probably better off using a javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
var selectedCardTypeEle = document.querySelector('input[name=radCCType]:checked');
if (!selectedCardTypeEle) {
    alert('please select a card type');
    return;
}
var cardType = false;
switch(selectedCardTypeEle.value){
    case 'F':
        cardType = "Freshman";
        break;
      case 'S':
        cardType = "Sophomore";
        break;
      case 'J':
        cardType = "Junior";
        break;
      case 'Sr':
        cardType = "Senior";
        break;
}
if (!cardType) {
    alert('please select a card type');
    return;
}
console.log(cardType);
```

And for reference, in jQuery that would look like this:

`$('input[name=radCCType]:checked');`

... so switching to jQuery later, if you discover you need to support mobile, won't be too tricky.

Another note, if you can eliminate the need for the single letter values, you can cut out a portion of that code -- I am not sure what your specific use case is.

**Documentation**

- Document Object Model (DOM) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM
- `document.querySelector` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector
- `switch` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch
- `document.forms` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.forms

Comment: all I had to do was add a name to the form and put it as frmInput and it ran. Thanks for the help tho!